# What are the ways to show different navbar based on if the user logged or not?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I want to know what are the best ways to show different navbar based on the fact that the user is logged or not.

I think about several ways to do it:

1. One way could be making two navbars in the HTML file and use CSS to make one display block and the other display none and switch between them using js.
2. Or another way could be using PHP "if statement"...

What other ways are there? and I know there is a lot of ways but what's the easiest way, and also with clean code.

Thank you all :).

Comment: The better way, for me, is to make it with PHP because your PHP code know if the user was logged or not and is able with if statement to render different code directly;

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly.
I would completely discourage your from using javascript/css based Hide/Show, One very good reason for it would be security, if anyone goes through your code can easily unhide your Navbar.

This is the case if you want to only show the Navbar if the user is logged in.

If you're writing PHP, mentioned in the comments by Lawrence, follow the MVC pattern and create your navbar as a View and include it ONLY when user is logged in.
PHP is a server-side language and it will not render anything if the `logged-in` condition is not full-filled.

Another advantage on using server-side rendering using PHP is that you can have multiple `Navbars` for different type of users. (Not the best practice , but you can do that).

Alternatively, if you wish to expand your knowledge in this field , you can achieve a far better result using front-end frameworks such as `ReactJS` or `Angular` etc...

Answer (score 0):

I definitely recommend you about not using `js` or any other client side languages!

What I'm gonna recommend : I don't know if it's counted as clean but ...

I wrote a web application and the navigation bar was depended on the user's access level,

so after the login, depend on user's access level, the path of the header file I included would be different.

```
<?php
    include(the path of the intended header/header.php);
?>
```

I got the intended path from database.

if your program isn't so sensitive about user access levels or you don't have a very dynamic navbar I think this is a good way!

otherwise wait for a pro to answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

I will prefer applying a classname to `<body>` by php and show/hide related elements by css, it can also control other elements on the page not only `nav`.

> Edit: Security is not a problem here because you should restrict accessing by php instead of just hide the links. The method here is just handling the layout.

```css
nav ul li {
  display: none;
}
body.guest nav ul li.guest,
body.logged nav ul li.logged {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<?php

  $user_logged = ($user->guest) ? 'guest' : 'logged';

?>

<body class="<?php echo $user_logged; ?>">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="guest"><a href="#">Nav 1</a></li>
      <li class="guest"><a href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
      <li class="logged"><a href="#">Nav 3</a></li>
      <li class="guest"><a href="#">Nav 4</a></li>
      <li class="logged"><a href="#">Nav 5</a></li>
      <li class="logged"><a href="#">Nav 6</a></li>
      <li class="guest"><a href="#">Nav 7</a></li>
      <li class="logged"><a href="#">Nav 8</a></li>
      <li class="logged"><a href="#">Nav 9</a></li>
      <li class="guest"><a href="#">Nav 10</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but Its not a good approach to load anything in DOM and hiding it with CSS. Think if there are some links that should be only visible to the logged user. If the guest user view the page source, they'll get that link easily.

Comment: It's not a problem. You should always restrict accessing on php level because users can always attempt to get in any pages by paste the link directly even they logged out.

Comment: Yeah absolutely, but why keeping all the things in the DOM that are not even shown to the user. Isn't it better to manipulate it on PHP level?

Comment: You are right, but just an option. Keeping things (maybe not all) in the DOM can make control of layout more easier by css and js. In my experience, sometimes it's necessary.